# jQuery: index slice function in iterations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slice function set up, calling the index of a `.test` to fade in the `.test` divs in blocks of 5. There's a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/JT4KB/2/ 
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.test').each(function (index) {
        $('.test').slice(0, 5).delay(500).fadeIn(300);
        $('.test').slice(5, 10).delay(1000).fadeIn(300);
        $('.test').slice(10, 15).delay(1500).fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

This works fine, but as the site will be content managed I want a more compact solution, thus instead of having to write a function for every 5 divs, is there a way to call this function by adding an extra `500` onto the delay for every 5 divs? If that makes sense? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remove `$('.test').each(function (index) {`!

Comment: What about a simple loop? You can get the number of divs by `$('.test').length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go sir.

http://jsfiddle.net/JT4KB/17/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
       $('.test').each(function (i) {
         var delay = Math.floor(i/5)*500 + 500;
         $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(300);
       });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: lol good question, poor copy and paste job from his fiddle, will fix

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new method to jQuery like this:

```
$.fn.eachSlice = function(size, callback) {
    var $t = $(this);
    for(var i = 0; i < $t.length; i += size) {
        callback.call($t.slice(i, i + size).get(), i / size);    
    }
    return $t;
}
```

and then

```
$(".test").eachSlice(5, function(sliceIndex) {
   $(this).delay(sliceIndex * 500).fadeIn();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JT4KB/16/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to achieve this. This loop has to loop 'the number of .test divs'/5 times:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        for (i=0; i<=$('.test').length/5; i++) {
            $('.test').slice(5 * i, 5*(i+1)).delay(500*(i+1)).fadeIn(300);
        };
    }, 1000);
});
```